# pulling a specific variable out of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

This is for an online form for product returns. The user selects from a menu, Refund, Replacement, 90DaysExpired, etc... (choices shown below). Each of those choices, has a corresponding message(inside a variable, also shown below). I want the value of the variable($tbrefund, $tbreplace, etc), based on the choice of the user, to be passed to the variable '$message'.

This is what I have so far, and I get the following error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: message**

```
$Rarray = array(
"Refund" => "$tbrefund",
"Replacement" => "$tbreplace",
"90DaysExpired" => "$expiredwarranty",
"ContactTech" => "$contacttech",
"RefundExpiredReplace" => "$outsiderefund",
"NoExRefund" => "$noexchange",
"ManuWarranty" => "$manuwarranty",
);

if (isset($Rarray[$Request]))
   $message =  $Rarray[$Request];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:
this is the line producing the error, I already know it's not relevent...

```
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Why would you downvote someone asking for help? It will only make new people reluctant to ask anything...

Comment: This notice is not emitted by the code you give. Show us the actual code.

Comment: have you tried "echo $Request" to check what is actually being submitted is correct?

Comment: you get downvoted for a poorly worded questions, when not enough information/testing/effort is made - not because the question itself is bad per say

Comment: Please update your question with the results of `var_dump($Request)`

Comment: Is this a site for anyone of any level to get help or a site for expert coders to ask other expert coders questions? I'm possibly at the wrong site ... my apologies to the lords of stackoverflow.

Comment: that sort of response wont help - as I said - if you post a good question, you get upvoted. Post a bad/poorly written question - and you get downvoted. This encourages you to improve the answer, which you have done, so the downvotes go away. If you cant take some constructive criticism, then no - this is not the site for you.

Comment: @jft5000 I apologize for other stackoverflow users who get a little click happy with the downvote button, but its no reason to get upset.  If you truly are looking for help, then help us help you by providing the necessary information that it would take to best answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because $Request is not set correctly.

```
if (isset($Rarray[$Request]))
{
   $message = $Rarray[$Request];
}
else
{
   $message = "Invalid";
}
```

So your actual question is *"why is $Request not working"?*

The answer is it depends on where $Request is coming from, so you need to show us some examples of $Request echoed (or var_dump() ) - but I would hazard a guess that you are sending the $Request lowercase (if it is via a URL or something) - but your array is capitalised.

Edit: and I hope you are not expecting your messages to be something other than "$tbreplace" or something.

I guessing you meant to do something like this?

```
$Rarray = array(
"Refund" => $tbrefund,
"Replacement" => $tbreplace,
"90DaysExpired" => $expiredwarranty,
"ContactTech" => $contacttech,
"RefundExpiredReplace" => $outsiderefund,
"NoExRefund" => $noexchange,
"ManuWarranty" => $manuwarranty
);
```

Comment: This actually helped. It was a problem with $Request. Not knowing how to ask, what to ask, or knowing what information is going to be relevant is an issue with being a beginner. I apologize for not providing enough information or wording my question poorly. Everything it working as planned now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: all good - its a learning experience - glad we could help and welcome to StackOverflow